# Resize image with skimage library without stretching

Tags: python, image, numpy

Hey i am trying to resize an image without stretching it but adding white pixels instead. I looked arround but i found nothing specifying how that can be achieved from within skimage. So instead i used numpy to add the extra pixels before the resize as arrays of [float(255)].

```
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.io import imsave
from skimage.transform import resize
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pylab import cm
import numpy as np
from skimage import morphology
from skimage import measure
from scipy import misc
def process(file_):
    im = imread(file_, as_grey=True)
    #im = misc.imread(file_)
    #im=np.fromfile(file_, dtype=np.int64)

    #Filler to avoid stretching
    orig_rows, orig_cols = im.shape
    print orig_rows, orig_cols
    if orig_rows < orig_cols:
        for addition in range(0,orig_cols-orig_rows):
            #adding white rows
            lst = np.array(list(float(255) for x in range(0,orig_cols)))
            im= np.vstack((im,lst))
    if orig_rows > orig_cols:
        for addition in range(0,orig_rows-orig_cols):
            #adding white columns
            lst = np.array(list([float(255)] for x in range(0,orig_rows)))
            im= np.hstack((im,lst))
    image = resize(im, (48, 48))
    imsave('test.jpg',im)
    imsave('test1.jpg',image)
    plt.imshow(im, cmap=cm.gray)
    plt.show()
```

When i view the image with pyplot it looks like this
[image: Image after numpy concatenations]
[image: original]
We can see that the columns have been added, but after i save the image with

```
image = resize(im, (48, 48))
    imsave('test.jpg',im)
    imsave('test1.jpg',image)
```

The the images look like negatives, and the resized image looks completely white(next to the dark its invisible on the sites background). Any ideas?

[image: Saved image][image: Resized and saved image]

Comment: I didn't get this problem when I tried your code. Could you give more info (py version, os, etc)

Comment: @IronManMark20 python 2.7, linux kali, amd64.
So you got the expected image?

Comment: yes I did on Windows 8.1 python 2.7.8 amd64. Both saves were black on a white background. You've tried upgrading skimage?

Comment: You can use numpy.pad function instead

Answer (score 1):

The code below should work. Note that the padded areas' color is not exactly white in order to see the image boundaries in the uploaded image. For white padding set `fill_cval = np.max(img)`.

```
def resize_padded(img, new_shape, fill_cval=None, order=1):
    import numpy as np
    from skimage.transform import resize
    if fill_cval is None:
        fill_cval = np.max(img)
    ratio = np.min([n / i for n, i in zip(new_shape, img.shape)])
    interm_shape = np.rint([s * ratio for s in img.shape]).astype(np.int)
    interm_img = resize(img, interm_shape, order=order, cval=fill_cval)

    new_img = np.empty(new_shape, dtype=interm_img.dtype)
    new_img.fill(fill_cval)

    pad = [(n - s) >> 1 for n, s in zip(new_shape, interm_shape)]
    new_img[[slice(p, -p, None) if 0 != p else slice(None, None, None) 
             for p in pad]] = interm_img

    return new_img

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from skimage.data import astronaut
from skimage.color import rgb2gray  # using luminance
from skimage.io import imsave
img = rgb2gray(astronaut())

# set desired image size
out_size = (30, 100)  # height, width

# set the color of the padded area. Here: "95% luminance"
fill_cval = np.max(img) * 0.95

resized_img = resize_padded(img, out_size, fill_cval=fill_cval)

imsave('img.png', img)
imsave('img_res.png', resized_img)
```

[image]

Comment: Note: consider using `interm_shape = np.ceil([s * ratio for s in img.shape]).astype(np.int)` instead of `interm_shape = np.rint([s * ratio for s in img.shape]).astype(np.int)` if running into problems with odd image sizes.